# Handlebars layout not being displayed (No error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

For some reason, despite my NodeJS server successfully receiving the POST request (as well as the data), it is unable to redirect to a handlebars layout. I've used a similar handlebars setup in other projects, so I don't think my configuration is incorrect. When I place `window.location.href = '/player'` just before the nested AJAX request, the server displays a 500 error. Without this line, the "Network" tab of my browser debugger shows no errors.

**client-routes.js** (POST /player route)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.use(express.json());

router.post("/player", function(request, response) {
  console.log("Player page requested.");
  t = []
  for(track of request.body.track_info) {
    t.push({
      image: track[0],
      artist: track[1],
      song: track[2]
    })
  }
  console.log("track_info (objects):",t)
  response.render("player_body", { t })
});

module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```
const clientRoutes = require('./client-routes');

const constructorMethod = (app) => {
  app.use('/', spotifyApiRoutes);
  app.use('/u', clientRoutes);

  app.use('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  });
};

module.exports = constructorMethod;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const configRoutes = require('./routes');
const routeNum = '8888'
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.json());

//-------------------------------------------------------------//
configRoutes(app)
//-------------------------------------------------------------//

app.listen('8888', function () {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${routeNum}.`);
});
```

**client.js**

```
$(function name() {
    mood = localStorage.getItem("mood")
    getTracks(mood.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
  });

  function getTracks(mood) {
      list_id = localStorage.getItem("playlist");
      $.ajax({
        url : "/gettracks",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: list_id, mood_data: mood },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res){
          console.log({ track_info: res });
          $.ajax({
            // Server should respond with 'player_body.handlebars'
            url: "/u/player",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ track_info: res }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(res){
              // Is never reached
              console.log("Tracks loaded.")
              window.location.href = '/u/player'
            },
            error: function(e){
              console.log(e)
            }
          })
        }
      });
  }
```

**File Structure**

```
core
│
└───public
|     -client.js 
└───routes
|      -client.js
|      -index.js
└───views
    │ 
    └───layouts
    |      -main.handlebars
    |
    -player_body.handlebars
```

So, the server executes the `console.log` statement, prints out the correct data, but the `response.render` does not produce a layout (previous view stays visible).

Comment: It looks like the POST `/u/player` endpoint should return JSON and _not_ a rendered view.

Answer (score 0):

the code in client.js

```
window.location.href = '/u/player'
```

hi, if you use this, the browser redirect to the url `/u/player` with GET method, maybe this is the problem is.

Comment: But by that point, the Ajax POST request would have gone through, so the server should have responded by displaying the new page.

Comment: I just tried, the `location.href` made a new GET request after the Ajax POST. Please use the chrome DevTools and see how the network goes

But you do not have the router to handle the url "/u/player" of GET method

Comment: Nothing changes after removing the GET request. Still no handlebars layout is displayed